# What is the effect of passing an array to Firestore database's orderBy clause?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Imagine the documents in my Firestore database represent recipes and each document has a 'tags' field, which is an array containing tags for that recipe (for example: spicy, French, vegetarian).

When a user searches for some tags, I use the array-contains-any operator to pull back all the recipes that contain at least one of the tags that a user has searched for. I then order the returned documents by the number of tags that have been matched. For example, if a user searched for 'spicy French vegetarian' then the documents whose 'tags' field contains all three of those tags appears first, followed by the documents whose 'tags' field contains two of those tags etc.

I am currently sorting manually using:

```
const userSearchedTags: string[] = [...] // array of tags searched for by user

recipes.sort((r1, r2) => {
  const r1Tags: string[] = r1.get('tags');
  const r2Tags: string[] = r2.get('tags');

  const r1TagMatchQuant = r1Tags.filter(r1Tag => userSearchedTags.includes(r1Tag)).length;
  const r2TagMatchQuant = r2Tags.filter(r2Tag => userSearchedTags.includes(r2Tag)).length;

  return r2TagMatchQuant - r1TagMatchQuant;
});
```

But I want to paginate this query, which requires them to be ordered by Firebase so I thought I might be able to use the orderBy clause in my query so that Firebase gives me the documents back already ordered by number of matched tags. If this worked then I would be able to use the startAfter() clause to paginate my query. I attempted this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('recipes')
  .where('tags', arrayContainsAny: userSearchedTags)
  .orderBy('tags')
  .get();
```

But it does not return the documents ordered by number of matched tags. I thought it might be returning the documents ordered by the length of the 'tags' array on each document, but further testing has shown it is not doing that either. So my question is how is Firebase ordering these documents when I pass 'tags' (a field that is an array) to the orderBy clause?

Also, is there a way to get Firebase to return the documents to me ordered by the number of matched tags or is the way I am doing it now (manually sorting after pulling back all documents with at least one matching tag) the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which document are returned is typically the same as however the documents are present in the index that is being searched. Assuming your tags are strings, then according to the documentation on [data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) that'd be:

> UTF-8 encoded byte order

So I expect it to be the order of that first tag that it matches, and definitely not the number of tags matched that you were hoping for. That type of results prioritization based on a calculated value is simply not something Firestore queries are made for as it would require that Firestore reorders the matches before returning them to you.

Comment: Thanks. What is the word you were going to use to describe the order? It looks like a word is missing after 'typically'

Comment: No, it is actually complete, just a bit hard to parse. I tried to clarify, although it's  now a bit wordy.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Just to confirm, if you were presented with this problem, would you implement it in the way I have then? (Pulling back all documents with at least one searched tag and manually sorting them)

Comment: That unfortunately makes pagination impossible, so I'd either skip that feature, or look for a way to expose the functionality that doesn't imply both sorting on a dynamically calculated value. If you need stronger search than Firestore offers, consider using a dedicated search engine.